# Multiple assertions (assertAll) - Kotest

Tags: kotest

Is any way to check multiple assertions in Kotest in  DSL style - without Assertions.assertAll method from JUnit?

Can I write something like

```
firstValue shouldBe 1
and secondValue shouldBe 2
```

Instead of

```
assertAll(
    { fistValue shouldBe 1 },
    { secondValue shouldBe 2 })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do it with `assertSoftly`. It probably is exactly what you want. From the [documentation](https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/soft-assertions.html)

```
assertSoftly {
  foo shouldBe bar
  foo should contain(baz)
}
```

Or using it as a parameter

```
assertSoftly(foo) {
    shouldNotEndWith("b")
    length shouldBe 3
}
```

However, your syntax works just as fine. You don't really need to assert softly.

```
firstValue shouldBe 1
secondValue shouldBe 2
```

will execute both assertions. If the first one fails the test crashes early. With `assertSoftly`, both assertions will be checked.